# making database available to other servers

Tags: php, javascript, database

OK, 
I'm not entirely clear how to ask this question, so please feel free to edit it.

Here's the idea.

I have a database that I think may be useful to webmasters.
I would like to offer, as a paid service, the inclusion of some interface with the database.
I want my database to dynamically populate drop-down option menus.

I understand how to do it when the database, requesting html/javascript and the processing php are all on the same server.

I'm not so sure whether this can be done if the requesting html html/javascript are on the webmaster's server, and the processing phps and the database are on my server.

I'm also not sure how to make sure that only authorized users can hook up to my database.

At this point, I am looking for a macro-level solution, not the code implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: and why would anyone want to go cross domain just to populate a drop-down box?

Comment: let's assume it's a great database and the webmaster does not want to bother with setting up the mysql on his own server, he just wants to insert several simple lines of javascript that would take care of it all?

Comment: "let's assume it's a great database " - full of gold? what exactly is a great database? I haven't come across many of those?

Comment: Well I could not understand why you want to do it! but you can easily achieve this with ajax! Webmaster can make a call to your server and you may insert html codes into their website where ever they want!

Comment: so, assuming you create some sort of a web service for these tens of rows of data, how will they pay for it? what's to stop them downloading once and storing in their database? I don't think you have thought this through.

Comment: Whether or not the database is actually valuable will be sorted out in the market, and has no bearing on the validity of this question. When providing data to third parties, most people expose a Web service (which can be authenticated for paid-service offerings).

Comment: Indeed, just as @Justin says, whether the data is really valuable enough to be paid for is an entirely different matter. But, my personal thoughts on the whole thing are: It'd need to be pretty darn crucial data for me to implement any sort of 3rd party API, much more so if it's paid for. Also, I'm not sure I'd simply include any 3rd party *HTML* into my page. Raw data that I output myself in my preferred format is fine, HTML is not. So, if your main business case is making the creation of *dropdowns* easier, you may lose the interest of any security conscious developer pretty quickly.

Comment: Justin - can it be authenticated "on the go?" - through some sort of auth field that gets checked by the webservice to make sure that it matches the url for which the service was requested?

Comment: @n00b, see my answer below. Basically, yes, you would essentially "sell" the API key as a subscription.

Comment: This is not a simple programming question. I think you should post a job on the careers site (after getting some venture money, after developing your business plan...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this would be to write a web service (whether SOAP, XMLRPC or REST) that requires the users to submit an API key with each request. The service would validate the key, talk to the database, and return results to the user in some standard format. The API key would (obviously) be unique for each user/subscription.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly connecting to remote database server, I suggest you to create a simple web service (such as a PHP page grabbing information from database, based on the request stated in query string you specified ) to generate XML / JSON for your web page.

Your web page, containing your drop down box, can make an AJAX request to fetch the XML & parse for data. With this mechanism, security problem caused by exposing the database can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the results of the request to the php script in JSONP format (json with padding). That allows the javascript to execute a callback method on the original webpage even though the service is on another domain.

You'd probably need some way of tracking state in your php code to determine if they're authenticated. One way would be to have the author of the 3rd-party webpage send an authentication token during their body onload to your php script. You could then mark the IP address of the client as "authenticated" and then all other requests from that same IP would return a valid result. Requests from a non-authenticated IP could return an error message.

IPs are obviously not unique in our world of NAT (network address translation). If you want it to be more fool-proof, you could generate your own token inside the PHP & send it back from the request to authenticate. The 3rd-party site would store that token in memory (or a cookie) & send it back to you on every request. You'd use that token as the proof of authentication on future requests, rather than the IP. This is basically how most servers do Sessions, PHP probably has something built in for that.